# How to specifiy a static IP address with docker-compose.yml version 3?

Tags: docker

Someone asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493490/provide-static-ip-to-docker-containers-via-docker-compose) - the problem is that it relates to version `2` which I am not using. Is it meanwhile possible to define a static subnet and a static IP address for each started container with docker-compose within the `docker-compose.yml` file?

Answer (score 7):

Use the following `docker-compose.yml` in order to start your containers in a predefined network with static IPv4 addresses:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  service1:
  image: service1:latest
  networks:
    service1_net:
      ipv4_address: 172.22.0.100
networks:
  service1_net:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.22.0.0/16
```

Comment: Works fine for me, also with v. 3.1.  Indentation missing after `service1:` but cannot edit and indent, because the changes are only 4 spaces, but S.O. requires edits to be 6 characters at least.  — I think the `driver: ...` line should be directly after `service1_net:`?